# Get a single response from all commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

How to make bot send a specific message when users use any commands. so when user use `!ping` or any command it should send a default message. cozz for sometime i need to stop bot responding to all command except 1 command.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the `on_message` event. Example code below.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot_prefix = '!'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx):
    msg = "Pong {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.startswith(bot_prefix):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Processing commands')

    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: It won't break if i have 2 bots ? `@client.event` and `@bot.event`  and can we add `if message.startswith(bot_prefix)` in  `@bot.event`

Comment: Would have to see your full code to be sure, but don't think it should break anything. Best way to be sure is to test.